# Is there any way to change the value of state variable in reactjs in such a way that it remains changed even after page refresh

Tags: reactjs

I set the value of state variable `popoverlist` through a handler function, but it gets changed to its original value after page refresh. Is there any way to permanently change it or change it for a certain time period?

```
this.state = {
      show: false, 
      buttonPush: 'invalid',
      list : [],  
      popoverlist : [{'p1': "Available", 'p2': "Available", 's1' : "Available", 's2' : "Available" , 's3' : "Available"},
                 {'p1': "Available", 'p2': "Available", 's1' : "Available", 's2' : "Available" , 's3' : "Available"}],
    };
  }


 handlePopoverList(keeptime,butdisable, count) {
    const newList = this.state.popoverlist.slice();
    if(keeptime === butdisable[0]) {
       if(butdisable[1] === 'Pool Table 1') {
        newList[count].p1 = "Booked";
       }
       else if(butdisable[1] === 'Pool Table 2') {
        newList[count].p2 = "Booked"; 
       }
       else if(butdisable[1] === 'Snooker Table 1') {
        newList[count].s1 = "Booked";
       }
       else if(butdisable[1] === 'Snooker Table 2') {
        newList[count].s2 = "Booked";

       }
       else if(butdisable[1] === 'Snooker Table 3') {
        newList[count].s3 = "Booked";
       }

       this.setState({popoverlist : newList});
    }
  }
```

After every page refresh, every element of `popoverlist` becomes 'Available' even if I set it to 'Booked'. I would want it to be equal to Booked even after page refreshes or for a certain time.

Comment: What happens, if you call this.handlePopoverList in componentDidMount()?

Comment: If you retrieve the data from a database on page load, you'll have the state stored. You can also try using [localstorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) for testing

Comment: Yeah, finally I am storing in state from the database. Thanks for the help.